# lua loadlib dll

Tags: dll, lua, package, assert, loadlibrary

I am trying to load a dll (it's not my dll) and it's written in C++

There are no exports to my knowledge, but it does what I need it to do once loaded.

assert(package.loadlib(dllfile,'')()
This throws an error, obv, "procedure not found" but the dll is still loaded, and works as intended.

if I call the above function a 2nd time, it crashes the client, so I need a checker of some sort.

my question is, is there a way to verify it's loaded?

Comment: Try `package.loadlib (dllfile, '*')`.

Comment: "procedure not found"

Comment: You cannot get this error when using asterisk instead of function name.  Show your code.

Comment: assert(package.loadlib(mypath .. [[\lib.dll]], '*'))()

Comment: Oops!  Lua 5.1 does not support asterisk in loadlib.  Try Lua 5.2 (or build LuaJIT with DLUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT option or download it from luajit4win.no-ip.org).  Why you trying to execute a function returned by loadlib invoked with empty function name?

Comment: The second argument to `loadlib` must be the initialisation function defined in the `dll` file you're trying to load. Also, store the value returned in some another variable. Like `init = package.loadlib(dllfile,'')`

Answer (score 1):

In Lua 5.1 when using `package.loadlib` as the second argument you must specify the name of a function actually exported by the DLL. It is not important which, if you only need to force the Windows dynamic linker to load the DLL (that seems your case).

To discover such names you can use [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (free tool). Open the DLL using `depend.exe` and look at the *export function list* panel (the first column has an **E** header label). Choose any function and use its name as the second argument (If it really doesn't have exported functions you are out of luck!). Try to choose a function labeled as C (not C++). C++ exported functions have mangled names that could cause problems.

For example, say you want to load kernel32.dll: using `depend.exe` you can discover that among all the exported functions there is one named `AddAtomA` (but any other C function would do). So you could use `package.loadlib` in this way:

```
assert( package.loadlib( "kernel32.dll", "AddAtomA" ) )
```

The `assert` call ensures that if the DLL cannot be loaded an error is issued.

To verify a DLL is actually loaded you can use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (another free tool).

- Make sure your script is running (you can put an `io.read()` statement in a suitable place to keep your script from terminating),
- then open ProcessExplorer window,
- select the process relative to your script (probably some `lua.exe`, but you can drag the "target" tool on ProcessExplorer toolbar to your script window to discover it)
- and type ctrl-D.

A lower panel should appear showing all the DLLs that the selected process is using. Browse the list to see if your DLL is listed.

Hope this helps.